# Transfer Value isn't showing up in the contract value

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging

So I'm totally new to ethereum. I'm asking you for help, maybe I don't understand the mechanics of this correctly.
I set up a contract und transferred a little eth to it. But the transfer value never showed up as the contract value. So of course as I tried to withdraw the eth, it didn't work. Is the transfer value stuck? Or is there a reason why it won't add up to the contract value?
Has it something to do with the gas? I couldn't understand the principle fully tbh.
That'a the contract: 0xE4Ee21e06Ce3356Ce341dc6d84fC1Cd075e5c9f2

Thank you for your help!

Comment: When you send Ether to an unverified smart contract, it won't reflect in the contract's balance unless the contract has a function to handle it. Try to verify the contract so that one can take a look at the contract code on the block explorer. Check if your contract accepts Ether properly and ensure your transaction has enough gas for execution.

Answer (score 0):

In the same transaction you used to send ether to the contract, the contract forward all the ether to another address. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x25ae321d71ca515673b49f8ee0ea1aa3dd38a0b287e5c330fed369e66f3dc71d

It is very likely you have followed instructions from a YT video and deployed a scam contract. In that case you have lost those ethers. You could contact the local authorities in your country that investigate online crimes.